# How to properly get values in OneToMany relationship based on field of "many" side?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Let's say I have an entity

> Restaurant

with field:

> ```
>  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
>  private Set<MenuEntry> menu;
> ```

MenuEntry entity has next field:

> ```
> @Column(name = "date_time_created", nullable = false)
> private LocalDate dateCreated;
> ```

which obviously represents date when entry was created.

**I need to write JPQL query which would give me Restaurant where set of menus includes entries with specified dateCreated.**

I've written method with next annotations:

> ```
> @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"menu"}, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
>
> @Query("SELECT r FROM Restaurant r WHERE r.id=:restaurantId AND  r.menu 
> IN (SELECT m FROM MenuEntry m WHERE m.dateCreated=:dateCreated)")
> ```

But when I try to perform this query I have "malformed numeric constant" exception. Could you please explain me, how to properly get values in my situation ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select r from Restaurant r JOIN r.menu m where m.dateCreated=:dateCreated and r.id=:restaurantId

Try this... This will work... No need to use inner query

Comment: Thank you! I've solved it already. Yap, I've just deceived myself - initially I was trying to get access to the field via @EntityGraph and it did not work, so I've decided to write query via subselect. Bad decision and stupid mistake. Now it is working. Peace!